# Why doesn't this infinite scroll work in IE?

Tags: php, jquery, infinite-scroll

The code below works as intended for Chrome and Firefox. For IE, it scrolls through the same content. I searched extensively for a solution but found nothing.

**Header**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).scroll(function()
{
   if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
   {

   $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
   $.ajax(
   {
      url: "http://www.hackedflashgames.com/loadmore.php",
      success: function(html)
      {
         if(html)
         {
             $("#wrapper").append(html);
             $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
         }else
         {
             $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
         }
      }
   });
}
});
</script>
```

**loadmore.php**

```
<?php
   include('db.php');
   $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6");
   if($stmt->execute()){
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
         echo'
         content here
         ';
      }
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE is renown for it's aggressive caching especially with AJAX.

Try adding some random query string to the URL for the ajax call (like a timestamp).

You could also specify this in your code : `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });`

Thus you won't have to manually add the query string, jQuery will take care of it.

Comment: This setup is global and can be set at any given time in your script file. You just need to make sure it is loaded before you make any call to the jQuery ajax function.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to add `$.ajax({ cache: false })` but it didn't work in IE. All of them including IE edge. What might be the problem?